# Do copper, copper(II) oxide, copper(II) hydroxide, copper(II) carbonate react with diluted sulfuric acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, transition-metals

> Which of the following will react with dilute sulfuric acid: copper, copper(II) oxide, copper(II) hydroxide, copper(II) carbonate?

Metals react with acids to give salt and hydrogen. So, copper will react with dilute sulfuric acid.

Metal oxides act as base. So, they neutralise acid to give salt and water. So, copper oxide will react with sulfuric acid.

Metal hydroxides are bases. So, they will neutralise acids. So, copper hydroxide will react with dilute sulfuric acid.

Carbonates react with acids to give salt, carbon dioxide and water. So, copper carbonate will react with dilute sulfuric acid.

So, my answer is all the given options will react with dilute sulfuric acid. Is this correct? The answers are not given in the book. I am afraid what if there are exceptions to the general reactions that I have written above and I am not aware of that.

Comment: Certainly true for Copper(II) oxide and copper(II) carbonate  https://edu.rsc.org/experiments/reacting-copperii-oxide-with-sulfuric-acid/1917.article   https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zysdgdm/revision/3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Metallic copper does not react with dilute sulfuric acid. Its redox potential is too positive to do it.
All other copper compounds do react with sulfuric acid, as you had suspected.