# Reaction of Copper and concentrated sulphuric acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reduction-potential

We know that dilute $\ce{ H2SO4}$ doesn't react with copper because copper has higher reduction potential ($0.33$) as compared to hydrogen ($0.00$).

However, it reacts with conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$ and gives $\ce{CuSO4}$ with $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$.

Why does this reaction take place?

Comment: Use `$\ce{<insert-compound>}$` to format chemical compounds over `<sub> (insert compound)</sub>`, It's easier and looks better

Comment: You can imagine concentrated sulfuric acid as an oxidising agent which supplies [O]. The copper takes the [O] and become CuO while sulfuric acid become sulfur dioxide. Then CuO reacts with remaining sulfuric acid to form $\ce{Cu2SO4}$. This is a grossly simplified version of what probably happens, but it gives you a sense of why conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$ can react with Cu.

Comment: You can a frame the nersnst equation , and see that the term coreesponding to concentration of SO4 2- comes in denominator so increasing concentration might make E cell >0 .

Comment: @RajatGolechha, Nernst equation should never be applied on concentrated solutions.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/145740/reaction-with-sulfuric-acid

Comment: Concentrated sulfuric acid contains the molecule $\ce{H2SO4}$ that makes a redox reaction with copper metal, Diluted solution of sulfuric acid do not contains any $\ce{H2SO4}$ molecule. They are all transformed into $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions, which are both unable to make a redox reaction with copper.